# How to make list view to listview.builder in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

```
buildComments() {

return StreamBuilder(

    stream: commentRef
        .document(postId)
        .collection('comments')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: false)
        .snapshots(),

    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return circularProgress();
      }

      List<Comment> comments = [];
      snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
        print(comments);
        comments.add(Comment.fromDocument(doc));
      });

      return ListView(
        children: comments,
      );
    });
}
```

> I was trying to convert it in list view.builder but it gives me error you can can't use list instead of Widget, Can anyone solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
              );
            });
```

Assuming you have `name` in the document.